# Getting inner most delimiters with Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I am trying to use Regular Expressions to the the inner most "The Info I want" text from this string:

{%%%=Select(MMGDS1,"cruise",{%%%The Info I want%%%}%%%}

I attempted to use this:

```
^(?!.*\%{3})\{\%{3}(.*?)\%{3}\}
```

But without luck.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negated class if the info you want doesn't contain any `%` character:

```
%{3}([^%{}]*)%{3}
```

A little more correct way would be using a negative lookahead in this format:

```
%%%((?:(?!%%%|[{}]).)*)%%%
```

I have put `{}` as well inside the characters that should not be matched as well.

Basically, `(?:(?!%%%|[{}]).)*` will match any character except `%%%`, `{` or `}`.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/rB4eE8)

Comment: I needed the full {%%% %%%} to be included in the search so I did \{%%%((?:(?!%%%|[{}]).)*)%%%\}  Is that ok?  It seems to work but maybe I am missing something later.

Comment: @Chris Oh, all right. You can use something like that indeed. And since you're already getting everything, you might as well remove the capture group: [link](http://regex101.com/r/tU2cQ9)

Comment: Thanks Jerry, I just put the \{  and \} on the outsides, but I think I need to do something with the inside %%% as well?

Comment: @Chris You're the one who can answer that question! I don't know what you intend to do with the match. If you need the part within `%%% ... %%%`, then you leave the capture group in there. You'll be able to access it through `.group(1)` on the resulting match object.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, since I am a newbee to Regex, I need to study some of the examples that you and other experts are doing. Overall, I need only the text inside the inner-most {%%% %%%} delimiters.

Comment: @Chris Then I would suggest you keep the one with the capture group (i.e. the one in my answer but with `\{` and `\}` at the ends, then access the part you need with `.group(1)`. There is yet another way to get the inner part. If you're keen to know about it, it's by using positive lookarounds: `(?<=\{%%%)(?:(?!%%%|[{}]).)*(?=%%%\})`

Comment: If I put this pattern into regexpal.com it comes back with an error immediately. I am not sure if the pattern is invalid of the regexpal.com website is not interpreting it correctly.  What do you think?

Comment: @Chris regexpal uses javascript based regex engine (which doesn't support lookbehinds). Java does support lookbehinds, so regexpal might not be a good site for you to test your regex on...

Comment: Jerry, well I used regex101.com tester and it works great! Guess I will change my regex testing choice!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can do lookahead assertions.  This works.

```
 #  {%%%((?:(?!{%%%|%%%})[\S\s])*)%%%}

 {%%%                         # Opening delimiter '{%%%'
 (                            # (1 start), 'The info you want'
      (?:                          # Cluster grp start
           (?! {%%% | %%%} )            # Lookahead, not delimiters '{%%%' nor '%%%}'
           [\S\s]                       # Ok, grab another character (any)
      )*                           # Cluster grp end, do 0 - many times
 )                            # (1 end)
 %%%}                         # Closing delimiter `%%%}`
```

Answer (score 0):

That's :

```
\{.*\{%{3}(.*)%{3}\}.*\}
```

Result :

Match 1:

```
{%%%=Select(MMGDS1,"cruise",{%%%The Info I want%%%}%%%}
```

Group 1:

```
The Info I want
```